# Exclude Grails filter from 2 (or more) controllers

Tags: grails

I have a Grails filter that I want to execute for every controller except 2 (`SimpleCaptchaController` and `ApiController`). I've been looking at [the Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/theWebLayer.html#applyingFilters) that describe how to define which controllers/actions/views a filter should be applied to, and there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to exclude a filter from 2 or more controllers.

I tried the following:

```
allExceptTwo(controller: 'simpleCaptcha', uri: '/api/**', invert: true)
```

But it seems you're not allowed to use `controller` and `api` together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried a simple regex like this:

```
allExceptTwo(controller: 'simpleCaptcha|api', invert: true)
```

I've done something like this before and it works.

Note: I think stop-restart of app is necessary for changes to filters to get picked up.